# How to get a shared path for dropbox node.js api when uploading a file?

Tags: node.js, dropbox

I am using this dropbox api library for node.js

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/node/upload.js

I am uploading a file using that code, but how do I get its shared path? The response I am getting is this which doesn't have it.

```
{ name: 'boo.txt',
  path_lower: '/boo.txt',
  path_display: '/boo.txt',
  id: 'id:0FFbLAVKMuAAAAAAAAAACA',
  client_modified: '2016-08-08T21:58:24Z',
  server_modified: '2016-08-08T21:58:24Z',
  rev: 'd4c5d5dc3',
  size: 3 }
```

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by "shared path" you mean the shared link for the file, you'll need to call [sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings__anchor) to create a shared link for the file with `path` being the path to the file.

Or, if one does already exist, you can call [sharingListSharedLinks](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingListSharedLinks__anchor) with `path` being the path to the file and `direct_only=true`.

Comment: an example on how to implement would be really helpful.

Comment: @Miraz I've answered your new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558459/get-link-to-the-uploaded-image-in-dropbox-using-js-and-sdk